# Dlookup Function in MS Access 2007 vba

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, lookup

I have a textbox that has a name **ISCO68Code** and **ISCO68Title** both are texts.

When I encode in ISCO68Code, a caption must appear on ISCO68Title that corresponds in my other table, libISCO1968.

---

Below is my Code Builder:

```
Private Sub ISCO68Code_AfterUpdate()

ISCO68Title = DLookup("ISCO68Code", "libISCO1968", "[ISCO68Code]=" & ISCO68Code&)

End Sub
```

Sadly, I got an error message:

> Compile error: Type-declaration character does not match declared data
>   type.

Any help will do.

Comment: How did you `Dim ISCO68Title As` ? Did you meant to do a function (with an output)?

Comment: @Fionnuala : It is probably text but there is no need for quotes, just remove the last `&`! ;)

Comment: @R3uK I Dim it as String

Private Sub ISCO68Code_AfterUpdate()
Dim ISCO68Title As String
ISCO68Title = DLookup("ISCO68Code", "libISCO1968", "[ISCO68Code]=" & ISCO68Code)

End Sub

Comment: Dim it as `Variant`, see MSDN ressource : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/office/ff834404.aspx Check out my edited answer! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need the quotes telling that the variable is text:

```
Private Sub ISCO68Code_AfterUpdate()

    ISCO68Title = Nz(DLookup("ISCO68Code", "libISCO1968", "[ISCO68Code]='" & ISCO68Code & "'"))
    ' If the control is a Label, set its Caption:    
    ' ISCO68Title.Caption = Nz(DLookup("ISCO68Code", "libISCO1968", "[ISCO68Code]='" & ISCO68Code & "'"))

End Sub
```

But your function doesn't make much sense, as DLookup will return the same *ISCO68Code* as you look up ... except if you just will check if it exists.

Comment: Yes, I want to check a record if it does exists in other table.

Comment: OK. Then it will work. If it is a _Label_, se revised answer how to set the _Caption_.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function :

```
Private Function ISCO68Code_AfterUpdate(ByVal ISCO68Code As String) As Variant

ISCO68Code_AfterUpdate = DLookup("ISCO68Code", "libISCO1968", "[ISCO68Code] = " & ISCO68Code)

End Function
```

---

```
Private Sub ISCO68Code_AfterUpdate_test()
Dim ISCO68Title As Variant

ISCO68Title = ISCO68Code_AfterUpdate(ISCO68Code)

'MsgBox ISCO68Title
Debug.Print ISCO68Title

End Sub
```